# div height not 100% of parent's height

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I have a information part on the left of the wrapper. the wrappers height is set to 100% and my left div for the info is set to 100%, but the height isn't 100%, it's auto, how can I make it so my left div height is equal to my wrapper div height?

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background:url(../images/wrap_bg.png);
    width: 1240px;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#wrapper #left {
    width:295px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%; 
    border-right: 1px dotted #fefbfb; 
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">some text</div>
</div>
```

This is somewhat of what I have http://jsfiddle.net/xD96D/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A percentage value for [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) is relative to the height of the containing box and `#wrapper` element (the container) doesn't have an explicit `height` value.

Hence the `100%` value for `min-height` property of the left `div` is calculated to `0`.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

> `min-height`
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage
>   value is treated as 0.

You should use `height: 100%` for the parent to get `min-height: 100%` to work for the children.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xD96D/1/)**.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Thanks for that info, learned something I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the height to 100% if the parent's height is either also set to 100%, either set to a static value, like 100 pixels.

Have a look at Hashem Qolami's answer. He did a better job explaining the problem as well posted up an example.